# how to store a reference to, and then use extern NSString const?

Tags: cocoa, extern, abrecord

i've made a plist as a dictionary with dictionary entries, one for each `ABRecord` property that i want to use later.

these dictionaries are **key/value** `NSStrings` like this:
`kABEmailProperty/email`.

i want to be able to use the unpacked plist to gather values from a specified `ABRecord` by enumerating the unpacked plist dictionary **(assume inRecord is an ABRecord)**:

```
__block NSMutableArray *valueGroup = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[self.propsDict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        NSString *valueString = [inRecord valueForProperty:key];
        if (valueString) { 
            NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:valueString forKey:obj];
            [valueGroup addObject:dict];    
                }
            }
        }];
```

how do i properly refer to **key**, so that it is the `ABRecord` global property reference in `ABGlobals.h` instead of the **string** that is stored in the plist ?

i've tried using &key, and (id)key, and (void *)key, but i'm really just *flailing* around.

i am unsuccessful in searching through the various questions regarding using global externs, although that has been informative.

Comment: Can you clarify things a bit further? What do you mean by "these dictionaries are key/value NSStrings like this: kABEmailProperty/email"? Can you give an example of one of these dictionaries? What do you mean by the "`ABRecord` global property reference"?

Comment: i made a plist dictionary which contains dictionaries of ABRecord properties (<AddressBook/ABGlobals.h>) using the property as the key as an NSString, and an NSString value that i want to use. For instance a key:@"kABEmailProperty" with value:@"email". then i want to use these (as in the block) to populate an array which i can use. i thought there might be a way to refer to the AddressBook global const by way of the NSString, like a caste or something, but of course that is not working.

Comment: You might try using the Address Book constants, not their names, as the dictionary keys. Then the value of `key` will be the same string as (or at least a string equal to) `kABEmailProperty`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you've got the following:

`NSString *foo = "kABEmailProperty";`

And you want to be able to do something like this:

`[inRecord valueForProperty:kABEmailProperty];`

Based on the value of foo. Correct? There's no way to do this directly, because the name "kABEmailProperty" isn't (easily) accessible at runtime; it's just a compile-time name.

My suggestion would be to make a dictionary with all keys in it; something like this:

`NSDictionary *keys = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:kABEmailProperty, @"kABEmailProperty", kABOtherProperty, @"kABOtherProperty", ..., nil];`

And then you can do something like this:

`[inRecord valueForProperty:[keys objectForKey:foo]];`

i.e. Make a mapping from the string `@"kABEmailProperty"` to the value that `kABEmailProperty` actually has.

Comment: i think you are saying that i need to map the property to the string if i want to use that string in the reference. i was actually wanting to be able to use @"kABEmailProperty" for the key, and @"email" for the value.

Comment: so i made a dictionary as per your suggestion and can reference it from the block, and i am still able to use the plist with my string 'labels' to create the needed array. thanks, this helps get me through this speed bump.